# Php Server Sent Event- Message sender and inbox

Tags: html, events, server-sent-events

I'm trying to make some php message sender and receiver Pages.
From the "Admin.php" page, administrator can send messages to the website visitors. And  the "receiver.php" page is the visitor's inbox.
Here is the codes:
Admin.php:

```
<form method="post" action="sender.php">
<input type="text" name="message">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Sender.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$message = $POST["message"];
echo "data: {$message}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

Receiver.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("sender.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
    };
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

why doesn't this work?

Comment: If you hover over the "stack-overflow" tag, it says: "DO NOT USE THIS TAG TO REFER TO THE Stack Overflow website. If you have a question regarding the site, please go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com, rather use this tag in reference to the error - Stack Overflow - which occurs when too much memory is used on the call stack."

You are not describing a stack overflow problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) which is why I removed the tag, and will remove it again now :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use "sender.php" to do two things.

From the admin form you need to submit to one php script that will store the messages, in a database of some kind.

Then in "receiver.php" you need to connect to a different PHP script, whose job is to keep polling that database for new entries, and when it sees one it should send it to the client. This latter PHP script will run in an infinite loop.

Comment: Can I do this without MySQL database?

Comment: I mean, by using fwrite and a text file?

Comment: By submitting the message in sender.php page

Comment: By submitting the message in sender.php page, the php script will write the message in a text file called messages.txt. and by polling, the website visitors will get the message from "messages.txt" file. This is the task.

Comment: I know how it works. But I don't know how to make it working. I mean, I don't know much php coding things

Comment: @Jishnuraj If you are asking me to write code for you, you can hire me through my company (URL in my profile). A cheaper option is to buy my SSE book, where you will find lots of sample code (some node.js, but most examples are in PHP): https://www.amazon.com/Data-Push-Apps-HTML5-SSE/dp/1449371930

Comment: BTW, yes, you can use fwrite and a text file, as your database; it does not have to be a full-on multiuser SQL DB like mysql. The main advantage would be no setup, the disadvantages are it will quickly get more complicated, and won't scale so well. (sqlite is kind of a middle ground.)

Comment: please don't use this stack overflow for advertisements. I have a non-working code and needs help from stack overflow users. So please don't send products(which will cost money) and If you know, how to solve the issue, then please edit the code.

Comment: @Jishnuraj People answering your questions here are doing it on a volunteer basis. The site is not a way to get people working for you, for free. IMHO, your initial question has been answered. It would be polite to upvote and accept it. If you have a follow-on question, that fits the Q&A format of StackOverflow, you should ask another question. Before doing that, I strongly recommend you put in a few hours effort to first search for similar questions.